# Track call chain from within mock functions in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, debugging, reflection

I need to write an automated test that should track the functions call chain. In the example below the functions are called `nativefn1` and `nativefn2`. I can't change their code to make the tracking possible so I need some workaround for this situation.

```
var async = require('async')

nativefn1 = function(input, cb) {
  setTimeout(
    function() { cb(null,"<" + input + ">") },
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  )
}

nativefn2 = function(input, cb) {
  setTimeout(
    function() { nativefn1(input, function(err,result) { cb(null,"<<" + result + ">>") } ) },
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  )
}

var callchain_counter = 0
var debug_results = { "???": [] }
var original = {
  nativefn1: nativefn1,
  nativefn2: nativefn2,
}

nativefn2 = function(input, cb) {
  var callchain_number = callchain_counter++
  debug_results[callchain_number] = []
  debug_results[callchain_number].push("Callchain #" + callchain_number + ": nativefn2 call:", arguments)
  original.nativefn2(input,function(err,result) {
    debug_results[callchain_number].push("Callchain #" + callchain_number + ": nativefn2 call result:", arguments)
    cb(null,result)
  })
}

nativefn1 = function(input, cb) {
  var callchain_number = "???"
  debug_results[callchain_number].push("Callchain #" + callchain_number + ": nativefn1 call:", arguments)
  original.nativefn1(input,function(err,result) {
    debug_results[callchain_number].push("Callchain #" + callchain_number + ": nativefn1 call result:", arguments)
    cb(null,result)
  })
}

async.parallel(
  [
    function(done) { nativefn2("Lorem",done) },
    function(done) { nativefn2("ipsum",done) },
    function(done) { nativefn2("dolor",done) },
    function(done) { nativefn2("amet",done) },
    function(done) { nativefn2("sit",done) },
  ],
  function(err,result) {
    console.log(debug_results)
  }
)
```

Upon execution this code prints `debug_results` like these:

```
{ '0': 
   [ 'Callchain #0: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'Lorem', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #0: nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<Lorem>>>' } ],
  '1': 
   [ 'Callchain #1: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'ipsum', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #1: nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<ipsum>>>' } ],
  '2': 
   [ 'Callchain #2: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'dolor', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #2: nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<dolor>>>' } ],
  '3': 
   [ 'Callchain #3: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'amet', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #3: nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<amet>>>' } ],
  '4': 
   [ 'Callchain #4: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'sit', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #4: nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<sit>>>' } ],
  '???': 
   [ 'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'ipsum', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<ipsum>' },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'Lorem', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'amet', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'dolor', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'sit', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<Lorem>' },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<amet>' },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<dolor>' },
     'Callchain #???: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<sit>' } ] }
```

But all `nativefn1` calls are untracked because I can't find a way to pass the `callchain_number` from mocked `nativefn2` to mocked `nativefn1`. Is it possible to access the call context or create some additional call context somehow to make this possible? Functions must be called in parallel.

Comment: you could overwrite `setTimeout`, but I assume thats just an example and in real live the function is more complicated?

Comment: That's just an example and `setTimeout` is used to simulate random delays.

Comment: Could have been done with a modified version of the co library and Promises, but I have no idea how to make this work in your (global) context.

Comment: I've found that it can be very easily done using domains but they're going to be deprecated. Do you know what would replace them?

Comment: Thought of them too... There is a project called "zone" from strongloop. Found this here: [https://github.com/strongloop/zone] and [https://domenic.github.io/zones/].

Comment: I thought it was dead https://github.com/strongloop/zone/issues/50 but `March 31, 2016` tells the opposite. That's strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it can be done using domains but since domains are deprecated I wonder what I should replace them with.

```
var async = require('async')
var domain = require('domain')

nativefn1 = function(input, cb) 
{
    setTimeout(
        function() { cb(null,"<" + input + ">") },
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
    )
}

nativefn2 = function(input, cb) 
{
    setTimeout(
        function() { nativefn1(input, function(err,result) { cb(null,"<<" + result + ">>") } ) },
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
    )
}

var context_counter = 0
var callchain_counter = 0
var debug_results = {}
var original = 
{
    nativefn1: nativefn1,
    nativefn2: nativefn2,
}

nativefn2 = function(input, cb) 
{
    var d = domain.create()
    var args = arguments
    d.callchain_number = callchain_counter++
    d.run(function()
    {
        debug_results[domain.active.callchain_number] = []
        debug_results[domain.active.callchain_number].push("Callchain #" + domain.active.callchain_number + ": nativefn2 call:", args)
        original.nativefn2(input,function(err,result) 
        {
            debug_results[domain.active.callchain_number].push("Callchain #" + domain.active.callchain_number + " nativefn2 call result:", arguments)
            cb(null,result)
        })
    })
}

nativefn1 = function(input, cb) 
{
    debug_results[domain.active.callchain_number].push("Callchain #" + domain.active.callchain_number + ": nativefn1 call:", arguments)
    original.nativefn1(input,function(err,result) 
    {
        debug_results[domain.active.callchain_number].push("Callchain #" + domain.active.callchain_number + ": nativefn1 call result:", arguments)    
        cb(null,result)
    })
}

async.parallel(
  [
    function(done) { nativefn2("Lorem",done) },
    function(done) { nativefn2("ipsum",done) },
    function(done) { nativefn2("dolor",done) },
    function(done) { nativefn2("amet",done) },
    function(done) { nativefn2("sit",done) },
  ],
  function(err,result) {
    console.log(debug_results)
  }
)
```

Output:

```
{ '0': 
   [ 'Callchain #0: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'Lorem', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #0: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'Lorem', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #0: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<Lorem>' },
     'Callchain #0 nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<Lorem>>>' } ],
  '1': 
   [ 'Callchain #1: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'ipsum', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #1: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'ipsum', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #1: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<ipsum>' },
     'Callchain #1 nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<ipsum>>>' } ],
  '2': 
   [ 'Callchain #2: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'dolor', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #2: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'dolor', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #2: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<dolor>' },
     'Callchain #2 nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<dolor>>>' } ],
  '3': 
   [ 'Callchain #3: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'amet', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #3: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'amet', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #3: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<amet>' },
     'Callchain #3 nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<amet>>>' } ],
  '4': 
   [ 'Callchain #4: nativefn2 call:',
     { '0': 'sit', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #4: nativefn1 call:',
     { '0': 'sit', '1': [Function] },
     'Callchain #4: nativefn1 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<sit>' },
     'Callchain #4 nativefn2 call result:',
     { '0': null, '1': '<<<sit>>>' } ] }
```